# Trim username Laravel + JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am using Laravel.

My task is:
I have username like: Steve Jobs but
I need to trim it to: Steve J.

Also, my problem is take this Auth name in app.js

```
var string = '{{ Auth::user()->name }}'; // it doesn't work
var res = string.split(" ");
var surname = res[1].slice(0,1);
  $('.name').text(res[0], ' ', surname, '.');
```

Comment: `.js` are not parsed by Blade, you could do it inline inside a `.blade` file where `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` will be available

Answer (score 0):

I moved script to blade file.

and did this:

```
    var string = '{{ Auth::user()->name }}';
    var res = string.split(" ");
    var surname = res[1].slice(0,1);
    $('.name').text(res[0] + ' ' + surname + '.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check It Out.

```
var string = '{!! Auth::user()->name !!}';
```